# Concatenating 3 columns but not all have data in them

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to concatenate 3 columns of data where 1 of the columns may contain no value. They are all number strings, and I want to concatenate each string with a dot in between. However, if the third column is blank, I don't want the extra dot to show.  I have tried doing a 2 step process where I concatenate columns 1 & 2 with a dot separator (because there is always data in columns 1 & 2). Then in a separate column I tried using an if statement to indicate that if the third column is blank, give me the results from the concatenated column I created, otherwise, give me the concatenated column + "." + third column.

Sample of data:

`Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Concat 1+"."+2   What I want

1           1310        1           1.1310         1.1310.1

19250       8550                    19250.8550     19250.8550

77171       5199        LAB         77171.5199     77171.5199.LAB`

In the first and third examples, I get what I want. But in the second example I end up with 19250.8550. - I don't want that extra dot at the end of the string.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
=A2&"."&B2&IF(C2&""="", "", ".")&C2
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: You can just `=A2&"."&B2&IF(C2="", "", ".")&C2`